# Loops in FPDF library

Tags: php, fpdf

I am new to using FPDF and cant get my head around it. Here is the simple case:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();


for($i=0; $i< 10; $i++){

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', "B", 12);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, "asd");


}
$pdf->Output();
```

The browser says it failed to load PDF document.
whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the code itself works for me. As stupid as it might sound, did you include the fpdf.php?

```
require('your/dircetory/fpdf.php');
```

Comment: Yes, theres no error in the code for sure, i just pasted it into a new file, added my require for fpdf and it works as intended.

Comment: damn it, it is working in Firefox indeed...but not working in Google Chrome

Comment: bad day for me today) thanx dude)